# How to create a composite self referential foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

PhpMyAdmin is giving me this error whenever I try to execute the following script:

It's self referencing, so it shouldn't have anything to do with its type and the syntax seems to be right, given the other examples on stackoverflow and MySQL's documentation.

Not sure if it'll help, but the code is a migration script generated by MySQL Workbench: Moving from Microsoft SQL to MySQL.

Does anyone have any clue as to what might be causing this error?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clinicalTrialEmployee` (
  clinicalTrialId INT NOT NULL,
  employeeId INT NOT NULL,
  clinicalTrialEmployeeTypeId INT NULL,
  roleName VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (clinicalTrialId, employeeId),
  CONSTRAINT FK_clinicalTrialEmployee_clinicalTrialEmployee
    FOREIGN KEY (clinicalTrialId , employeeId)
    REFERENCES clinicalTrialEmployee (clinicalTrialId , employeeId)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

What in the world does it even mean for a field to reference itself?  That's a new one on me.  I've had one column on a table be a foreign key for another column on the same table, but I've never heard of a column referencing itself.  Do you understand what such a foreign key constraint is supposed to accomplish?  I mean that quite literally: what is the actual point of this?  Most likely the answer is that MySQL doesn't support this.  There are many variations between different "dialects" of SQL, and just because an export from a Microsft SQL server created this SQL doesn't mean that MySQL supports either the syntax **or** the principle in general.

Someone else might come along with more information, but in the meantime I wouldn't try to just reproduce this exactly as is.  I would figure out what it was actually supposed to accomplish, figure out if that even still matters, and then find a way to do the equivalent in MySQL (if it is even possible).

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is another field in the table to reference a related record.  For instance, you may have a supervisor_id pointing to a supervisor employee that is also in the clinicalTrialEmployee table.

The way the foreign key is written now, it is just referencing itself, which becomes an infinite loop.